# Exchange 2003 R2 is deleting mails

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007, mailbox

I know it sounds familiar, and of course there can be several reasons and appropriate solutions to these, but I tried nearly all (I know) of them. A user of my company uses a mailbox, stored by an Exchange 2003 Server. We recognized, that every more than 30 days old mail disappear. We checked the auto-archiving option in Outlook 2007, the views and rules set by the user, but found nothing unnormal. Next we deleted the mailbox (after we made a backup of its content), and created a new one. But this didn't solve the problem. Has anyone an idea to this problem?

Thanks,
Haniball

Comment: On a side note, there's no such thing as Exchange Server 2003 R2. I'm assuming you mean Exchange Server 2003 running on Windows Server 2003 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to see if there is another client (Outlook ) running with that mailbox.. It could have archiving or a rule on it.

Comment: Does the user access the mailbox via a handheld? If so, I would check the handheld.